# How can I fix exporting errors/missing reference photos in the Mac Photos app?

Tags: macos, photos, catalina, photos.app

I'm using the Mac Photos app on macOS Catalina (10.15.4)

I have a Photos library that dates back to 2007 and was originally an iPhoto library. Ever since it was migrated to a Photos library, there have been issues with exporting photos from late 2013 through mid 2015.

When I choose File > Export on these photos, I get an error message:

> The export operation failed to create a file for the photo identified below:
>
> Example.jpeg Unknown Error (4)

When I click Reveal in Finder, nothing happens.

I have checked out this Stack Exchange article which describes the same problem I think:
[How can I repair missing referenced photos in Photos.app on MacOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376833/how-can-i-repair-missing-referenced-photos-in-photos-app-on-macos-catalina)

However, when I open `photos.sqlite` in DB Browser for SQLite the `ZFILESYSTEMBOOKMARK` table is empty and the `ZPATHRELATIVETOVOLUME` table does not exist.

Basically, a large number of my photos exist in the Photos library but can only be accessed in Photos. They cannot be exported. Ideally, I would like a way to find where Photos is storing those files so that I can either repair the database or re-import the photos so that they work correctly.

Comment: I have the same issue. In addition to not being able to export the photos (unknown error 4) it is also not possible to edit the photos (cannot load adjustments). See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399027

Comment: I have reported the issue to apple many months ago and they escalated it to engineering. But there is no solution yet and they have stopped responding to my status inquiries.